# Home PC with VPN connection i cannot login from Work PC?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, iptables

I have a Ubuntu PC home running,  with a dynamic IP address. 
Now I have rented a VPN service. zorrovpn.com

When my PC starts up, then immediately VPN connection goes via zorrovpn.com

```
/etc/openvpn/zorrovpn.conf
```

That's all right.

Now I want to access from work, my home PC via SSH. 
Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Can someone tell me how I need to change the IP tables so I can allow the incoming connection to my home PC And only the SSH connection?

Comment: It is entirely unclear to me (from looking at their web page) that ZorroVPN will allow you to do this. Did ZorroVPN give your VPN a static endpoubt and have they committed to not blocking inbound traffic to that IP. Similarly, is your work allowing ssh traffic out its network?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not understand you. 
Zorrovpn gave me nothing extra.
I just booked this service.

Comment: What makes you think that their service will let you do what you want? Ive not used it (but do use OpenVPN extensively in different configurations, and what to do seems to be the opposite of what they are offering - ie anonymity and privacy - when you want traceability [static IP] and public access into your systems.

Comment: Actually, on rereading this your question is unclear. Did you get Zorro to help make your system reachable from work or us Zorro interfering with this reachability? If its the latter, do you have a static at work? (The problem will be a changed default gateway)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Accepts only SSH connections from your work network.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4/24 --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

where 1.2.3.4/24 is the public address of your work network.

Comment: I'll test that and give feedback. 
Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. 
Do you know why?